# Save Changes Does not work in Encapsulated UnitOFWork class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I am trying to create a generic repository using entity framework code first and encapsulate everything in a UnitOfWork but something must be wrong because when I trying to add that and use my encapsulated SaveChanges it does not work.
Here is my repository code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext Context { get; set; }
    private DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get { return Context.Set<T>(); }
    }

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    } 

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {

            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        DbSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);   
        }
    }

    public virtual void Remove(int id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

And here is my UnitOfWork code:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory;

    private DatabaseContext DbContext
    {
        get { return new DatabaseContext(); }
    }

    public IRepository<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return repositoryFactory.GetRepository<Product>(DbContext);
        }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        repositoryFactory = new RepositoryFactory();
    }

    public void SavaChanges()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is the code I am calling to Add data and get data:

```
var sa = new UnitOfWork();
var repository = sa.Products;;
var result = repository.GetAll();
var resultbyId = repository.GetById(3);

 var product = new Product()
 {
     Name = "sddasd",
     CategoryId = 1,
     SubcategoryId = 1,
     Price = 21,
     Description = "dsadasfas",
     ImagePath = "Dsadas",
     NumberOfProducts = 29
  };
   repository.Add(product);
   sa.SavaChanges()
```

After running this code it seems that for some reason my SaveChanges incapsulated in my UnitOfWork class does not work.

But if for example I would add this line right after DbSet.Add(entity)

```
Context.SaveChanges()
```

It seems that the object get's added to the database.

How can I make my UnitOfWork SaveChanges method to work?

Comment: What about implementing IDisposable on Repository<T>, and reusing the unit of work thats built into EF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is here:

```
private DatabaseContext DbContext
{
    get { return new DatabaseContext(); }
}
```

What you are effectively doing is creating a new context *each time* your property is accessed. While your `Repository<T>` correctly saves one context and re-use the same one, when you call `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges` you are saving on a *newly created* context, with no changes.

In the spirit of a UnitOfWork, you want your context to live the entire lifetime of the enclosing class (`UnitOfWork`). Try this:

```
private DatabaseContext dbContext;
private DatabaseContext DbContext
{
    get { return dbContext ?? (dbContext = new DatabaseContext()); }
}
```

This way, your `DatabaseContext` will only be created once in the lifetime of your `UnitOfWork`, upon the first access to the `DbContext` property.

Comment: Even better, the context should be injectable into the repository. This way you could reuse the same context across different repositories in the same unit of work.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The context is already "injected" in the repository. It's passed as a constructor argument. Unless I'm miss-reading his code.

Comment: True, I must have missed that.